# Yaml nested arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, yaml

Trying to convert nested php array

```
$ar:3 [▼
  "sotr" => array:5 [▼
    0 => {#190 ▼
      +"sId": "1"
      +"sFIO": "Родион Романович Мишин"
      +"sSalary": "7477.59"
    }
    1 => {#192 ▶}
    2 => {#193 ▶}
    3 => {#194 ▶}
    4 => {#195 ▶}
  ]
  "ticket" => array:5 [▶]
  "task" => array:4 [▶]
]
```

into YAML string by using Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml in Laravel. So, when I'm using

```
$data = Yaml::dump($ar);
```

I see empty array like this:

```
sotr:\n
    - null\n
    - null\n
    - null\n
    - null\n
    - null\n
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Are those `\n` newlines or two separate characters? Where is the empty sequence (YAML doesn't have a collection type array)? The only sequence I see there (assuming `\n' is a newline) has 5 elements.

Comment: instead of null I need the names of table fields - sId, sFIO, sSalary. How i can create correct output array?

Comment: @NastyaKeller Do #190, #192 and others mean those are objects instead of arrays (numbers being their ids)? I don't think dump can deal with anything other than scalars and arrays.

Comment: probably have to look for another solution. thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it! Probably this solution not so smart, but it works. 
Convert array into JSON string:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($ar), true);
```

Then using Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper class

```
$dumper = new Dumper();
$yaml =  $dumper->dump($data);
```

And here the YAML formatted string:

```
sotr:
    -
        sId: '1'
        sFIO: 'Родион Романович Мишин'
        sSalary: '7477.59'
```